# A bound of Cesàro mean of the Fourier series of bounded function

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{T} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $m \leq f(x) \leq M$ for some $m, M \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $x \in \mathbb{T}$. We have, the $k$-th Cesàro mean of the Fourier series $f$:
$$\sigma_k[f](x) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F_k(t)f(x-t)\ dt,$$
where $F_k(t)$ is the Fejér kernel.

To show: $m \leq \sigma_k[f] \leq M$ for all $x \in \mathbb{T}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I thought because $m \leq f(x) \leq M$ , then $m \leq f(x-t) \leq M$, by the periodicity of $f$. Using $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F_k(t)\ dt = 1$, it is clear that $m \leq \sigma_k[f] \leq M$. Then I'm starting to doubt whether I can take such conclusion. I think this reasoning will work if $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{T}$. Any comments or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that Fejér kernel is an approximate to identity, and  $$F_k(t)=\frac{1}{k+1}\left(\frac{\sin\frac{(k+1)t}{2}}{\sin\frac{t}{2}}\right)^2\geq 0.$$ So, $$m=\frac{m}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi F_k(t)\ dt\leq\sigma_k(f)(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi F_k(t) f(x-t)\ dt\leq \frac{M}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi F_k(t)\ dt= M.$$

> Note that there is another alternative formulation of Fejér kernel
> given by $$F_k(t)=\sum_{\ell=-k}^k\left
>  (1-\frac{|\ell|}{k+1}\right)e^{i\ell\theta}.$$ But, we do not need this
> here.

Comment: Maybe you mean $m = m\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}F_k(t)\ dt$? Since the integral of the Fejér kernel is 1, right?

Comment: Yes, the integral of the Fejér kernel is $1$, some use the factor $\frac{1}{2\pi}$, some not. It depends on the definition of Fejér kernel, in order to make it an approximate to identity we have to multiply it by suitable constant.

Comment: So we don't have to worry that $f(x)$ could be negative?

Comment: No, you don't need to consider this special case as Fejér kernel is non-negative, as I have written.

Comment: What do you mean with "it's an approximate to identity"?

Comment: Besides, how do you conclude those inequalities?